# Webpart to Create CSV file in Local Directory

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am facing problem in creating CSV file through webpart in local directory. I have tried different methods to achieve this but in vain.
Anyone here ever before have created file?

Comment: What did you already tried? Do you mean local with local SharePoint Server or local Client of the user which called the page with the Webpart?

Comment: try to sell the user using export to excel (list view OOB functin), 
if not try SSRS, otherwise custom C# code.